# How do we show the result of calculation on Front End done based on the user input in Django?

Tags: python, django, user-input

I am working on a Django Project, where a student will write his/her course name in a form and click on Calculate button and the system will use the Fuzzy Logic to calculate the performance of students based on the details of that specific course and then show the result of that calculation below the Calculate Button.

What I have done so far are below.

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from .forms import PerformanceCalculatorForm
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import Subject, Detail
from .fuzzy_logic_algo import fuzz_algo


def performanceCalculator(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        performance_form = PerformanceCalculatorForm(request.POST)

        if performance_form.is_valid():
            sub = performance_form.cleaned_data.get('subject')

        skype = Details.objects.filter(subject__subject=sub, user__username=User.username).get('skype_session_attendance')
        internal_course = Details.objects.filter(subject__subject=sub, user__username=User.username).get('internal_course_marks')
        prg_lab = Details.objects.filter(subject__subject=sub, user__username=User.username).get('programming_lab_activity')
        mid_marks = Details.objects.filter(subject__subject=sub, user__username=User.username).get('mid_term_marks')
        final_marks = Details.objects.filter(subject__subject=sub, user__username=User.username).get('final_term_marks')

        result = fuzz_algo(skype, internal_course, prg_lab, mid_marks, final_marks)

        context = {
            'result': result,
        }

        return render(request, 'users/performance_calculator.html', context)
    else:
        performance_form = PerformanceCalculatorForm()

    return render(request, 'users/performance_calculator.html', {'performance_form': performance_form})
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from PIL import Image

class Subject(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} ({})'.format(self.subject, self.user.username)


class Detail(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subject = models.OneToOneField(Subject, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    skype_session_attendance = models.FloatField()
    internal_course_marks = models.FloatField()
    programming_lab_activity = models.FloatField()
    mid_term_marks = models.FloatField()
    final_term_marks = models.FloatField()

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.subject, (self.user.username)} Details'
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms

class PerformanceCalculatorForm(forms.Form):
    class Meta:
        fields = ['subject']
```

performance_calculator.html:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'esacp/main.css' %}">

        <title>Expert System for Assessing Programming Course Performance</title>

    </head>

    <body>
        <main role="main" class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    {% if messages %}
                        {% for message in messages %}
                            <div class="alert alert-{{ message.tags }}">
                                {{ message }}
                            </div>
                        {% endfor %}
                    {% endif %}

                    {% if not request.user.is_superuser and not request.user.is_staff %}
                        <div class="account-heading">
                            <h2>
                                Performance Calculator
                            </h2>
                        </div>

                        <div class="content-section">
                            <form method="POST">
                                {% csrf_token %}
                                <fieldset class="form-group">
                                    <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Profile</legend>
                                    {{ performance_form|crispy }}
                                    {{ result }}
                                </fieldset>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    {% endif %}
                </div>                
            </div>
        </main>

        <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
        <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Can anyone tell me that how would I accomplish it that a user (student) enters the course name in the form when he/she is on `.../performance_calculator.html`, his record is saved, and matched with the courses assigned to him, after the matched, the activity details of student that course is taken and those are assigned to separate variables, the those variables are passed to `fuzz_algo()` function, then the result of that function is printed on the Front End?

I have been working on it since 2 days and not getting it. Any help will be surely appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me go with some really problematic things first. Your `PerformanceCalculator` view, in the POST conditional, you never `save()` the form, and therefore your next queries will return empty objects, which I believe the `fuzz_algo` will return None (Assumption) and displays nothing on the render.

Actually best practice is: on the last line of your POST conditional, use `redirect` instead of `render` as it will load you again the page without the POST data.

And I think that all the above thing you have tried already (because you said you tried 2 days), but wonder why it still renders nothing, because by `redirect` it will ask again with a GET request and will lose the data in the variable `result`.

Now with the "not so important" thing, as I see in your code and you don't have intention of saving your form in database, this is probably a better approach on the Client Side instead of Server Side. To do it on the server side please check https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/sessions/ to use sessions variables to keep it alive and not lose after `redirect`, also there is EASY work around (but doesn't work in all the cases) is to .. let's say "abuse" the `messages` library of `django`, it will pass a message to the client side on your next LOAD.

So on your **views.py** import the `messages` library and add this before `redirect`

```
messages.success(request, result)
```

Now **in your template** add this

```
  {% if messages %}
      {% for message in messages %}
          {{ message }}
      {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
```

Comment: @KhubaibKhawar Glad to know it worked for you, but as you can see, you didn't have intention to save the form, so maybe a better approach NEXT TIME is to do it on Client side, as it will be better to style the tags but also no need to reload the page for results.

Comment: Thanks @Paaksing, actually I am new to Django and I have not learnt about sessions variables yet. I have actually learnt basic level Django for this Project and I thought it would be enough to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to Django, but I think I did something similar to what you are trying to do.
1. With a model similar to yours - had the user fill out the form and then made sure the model was populated with the data from the form. I didn't realize at first that I needed to make sure every field in the form was filled out or nothing would be saved to the model. (It is in the docs, I just didn't pick up on it).
2. Then when I wanted to use the data in the model, I just made sure that the model was imported.I also imported a separate python file to perform the computation on the parameters.

Then in the view I assigned a variable = to the model object for example for the Model Search_Profile in my case I had

```
params=Search_Profile.objects.last()
```

since in my case I just wanted the last profile, but you could make it any object you wanted.

With that information I could then import the function from a .py file In my case

```
C=calculate(params.keyword_string,params.other_string)
```

At that point I could then render the template with both the parameters and whatever I needed from the calculation function in the .py file by using

```
return render(request,'mainapp/show_calculation.html',{'params':params,'new_entries':new_entries,'C':C})
```

It took me a while to figure that this worked, and maybe there are better ways, but it at least worked for what I was trying to do.

Looking at your code, I suspect you're a better coder than I am, but maybe the above might help. In your form you only have the subject field and don't have the user field. In my situation I think that led to my model not being filled.

The other thing I had to do to figure it out for my case was to get away from crispy forms or widget-tweeks, but I don't think that matters much.